# How do I approach changing URL's on a long scroll page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, fragment-identifier

I have been tasked with creating one long page that will have various small articles for the user to scroll through. Each of the article sections have a category and I need for the URL to reflect that category being viewed. I am aware that `history.pushState()` can be used to change a URL when triggered. But it is the logistics that I am unclear about.

I have already figured out a way to have the main menu links jump down to the appropriate category using the following code and it seems to work fine.

```
$('a.js-link').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault; // dont actually follow the link
    var category = $(this).data('category-id'); // get the id we should anchor to
    location.hash = '#' + category; // jump to the location hash id
    history.pushState("", "", category); // make the url pretty again
    return false; // dont append #category to the pretty url
});
```

However, when a user scrolls down and a new category starts appearing the URL should change to example.com/category2 (as category 1 is the first and will appear on initial page load), user keeps scrolling then URL is changed to example.com/category3. Now if the user scrolls back up it should change back to example.com/category2. Am I simply listening for the scroll event and then checking to see if an element is in the viewport? How do I handle a situation where the upper half of the page is showing a previous category and the lower half the next?

My other roadblock is how to handle linking directly to a specific category on the page. If a user is linked directly to example.com/category5 the page should be loaded and anchored down to the category5 section.

I should mention that I plan on using [jquery.lazy.js](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/) to load in the main container div's for categories in order to decrease initial page load time. Due to this, I cant use jquery to scroll down to an element since it calculates the size of the element/page and scrolls down by that amount, but then once the content is loaded in it is no longer the appropriate category in view. Although I am open to changing this approach if it majorly affects the ability to change the URL.

Sorry for the wall of text! I am not looking for someone to code this for me, but to push me in the right direction!

Comment: _Am I simply listening for the scroll event and then checking to see if an element is in the viewport?_ Yes - if unique IDs are used, the page will scroll to #id on the URL

Comment: It should be `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @mplungjan It will be unique ID's but what I need is for the URL to change while scrolling the content, not for the URL to scroll me to the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is I typically use `history.replaceState()` to accomplish this but there is a lot more going on. MDN describes this method:

> Updates the most recent entry on the history stack to have the
>   specified data, title, and, if provided, URL. The data is treated as
>   opaque by the DOM; you may specify any JavaScript object that can be
>   serialized.

In practice, how this works out is that I create a state object with the different states being my page sections. I often use this in conjunction with the excellent [Waypoints plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/), triggering a state change based on a waypoint. This code is pretty easy to understand, read my comments which will walk you through it.

```
// 1- Sets up state object that will store each page section 'state'
var stateObj = { state0: "group" };

// 2- Setups up waypoint to indicate a new section
var yourNameWaypoint = new Waypoint({

  // 3- Target an ID for waypoints to watch, corresponds to a page section
  element: document.getElementById('page-id-target'),
  handler: function(direction) {

    // 4- Create down direction handler
    if (direction === 'down') {

      // 5- Assign stateObj a page state that corresponds to your page section
      stateObj = { state1: "page-section-1" };
      history.replaceState(stateObj, "Section Title", "#new-page-section-slug-here");
    }

    // 6- Do the same thing in the other direction now, reseting the URL to what it was before the waypoint was hit
    if (direction === 'up') {
      stateObj = { state0: "original-state" };
      history.replaceState(stateObj, "Original Page Section Title", "original-page-slug-here");
     }
   }
});
```

To get the hashes to correspond to scroll positions is a bit more difficult. I modified a pretty good script to get this to work (http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/rkocah23/), but I'll post the original here.

The idea is pretty simple. Basically, you are reading each URL hash you created in the function above within `init` and then feeding that into `scrollToCurrent` part of the function when they match, using `history.pushState()`. I've found I like to put a little delay in the scroll animation to make the behavior feel more normal (set at 500ms below but you could adjust that).

```
(function(document, history, location) {
  var HISTORY_SUPPORT = !!(history && history.pushState);

  var anchorScrolls = {
    ANCHOR_REGEX: /^#[^ ]+$/,
    OFFSET_HEIGHT_PX: 50,

    /**
     * Establish events, and fix initial scroll position if a hash is provided.
     */
    init: function() {
      this.scrollToCurrent();
      $(window).on('hashchange', $.proxy(this, 'scrollToCurrent'));
      $('body').on('click', 'a', $.proxy(this, 'delegateAnchors'));
    },

    /**
     * Return the offset amount to deduct from the normal scroll position.
     * Modify as appropriate to allow for dynamic calculations
     */
    getFixedOffset: function() {
      return this.OFFSET_HEIGHT_PX;
    },

    /**
     * If the provided href is an anchor which resolves to an element on the
     * page, scroll to it.
     * @param  {String} href
     * @return {Boolean} - Was the href an anchor.
     */
    scrollIfAnchor: function(href, pushToHistory) {
      var match, anchorOffset;

      if(!this.ANCHOR_REGEX.test(href)) {
        return false;
      }

      match = document.getElementById(href.slice(1));

      if(match) {
        anchorOffset = $(match).offset().top - this.getFixedOffset();
        $('html, body').delay(500).animate({ scrollTop: anchorOffset});

        // Add the state to history as-per normal anchor links
        if(HISTORY_SUPPORT && pushToHistory) {
          history.pushState({}, document.title, location.pathname + href);
        }
      }

      return !!match;
    },

    /**
     * Attempt to scroll to the current location's hash.
     */
    scrollToCurrent: function(e) { 
      if(this.scrollIfAnchor(window.location.hash) && e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    },

    /**
     * If the click event's target was an anchor, fix the scroll position.
     */
    delegateAnchors: function(e) {
      var elem = e.target;

      if(this.scrollIfAnchor(elem.getAttribute('href'), true)) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  };

    $(document).ready($.proxy(anchorScrolls, 'init'));
})(window.document, window.history, window.location);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a more of a complete answer than I could have hoped for. I have not yet had a chance to give it a try but reading through it, it seems robust. I do have one question though: would it be possible to achieve all of this without any hash's in the URL? so instead of example.com#category5 we could have example.com/category5 and still have it anchored down?

Comment: No worries. I guess you could do it without updating the URL hash, but then how would people be able to uniquely navigate to a specific area? My use case was built around wanting to have unique URLs so YMMV.

Comment: I completely agree and I think I will have to make a case to use hash instead of "pretty" URL's. I was just curious if you had a suggestion on how to make this script compatible without using the hash. Much appreciated!!

Comment: This assumes traditional routing, where slashes are reserved for use by the server. Maybe you could do it with slashes at the code level - but you'd have to control for that at the server level too, probably by putting some 301 redirects into an `.htaccess` file. To really get where you want to go, you'll need something like angular's router that controls paths itself. `#` is so much easier in comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I will make a proof concept and if your answer works I will approve it, regardless of if it is the implemented solution or not.

Comment: Site I built is still in beta but you can see this in action: http://new.ltk.com/capabilities